# JSON.NET serialization of System.Drawing.Color with TypeNameHandling

Tags: c#, json.net

I want to serialize a `Dictionary<string, object>` that may contain `System.Drawing.Color` values or other types as values.  I create a serializer with `TypeNameHandling.Auto`, and this works for most classes, but not `Color`.

Example code: (DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UvphQO)

```
public class Program
{
    class A { }
    class B { }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dict["Foo"] = new A();
        dict["Bar"] = new B();
        dict["Baz"] = new object();
        dict["Rainbow"] = Color.FromArgb(20, 20, 20, 20);

        var ser = new JsonSerializer
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
        };
        var w = new JsonTextWriter(Console.Out)
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };
        ser.Serialize(w, dict);
    }
}
```

The resulting output:

```
{
  "Foo": {
    "$type": "Program+A, mi1i2eqo"
  },
  "Bar": {
    "$type": "Program+B, mi1i2eqo"
  },
  "Baz": {},
  "Rainbow": "20, 20, 20, 20"
}
```

As expected, instances of `A` or `B` in the dictionary have the needed `$type` metadata for reconstruction.  But instances of `Color` do not.  When this json is deserialized, `dict["Rainbow"]` is a `System.String`.

There are many ways I could work around this, but the preferred solution would be to figure out why the serializer is doing something seemingly incorrect with `$type` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`System.Drawing.Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Color(v=vs.110).aspx) has an associated [`TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colorconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which Json.Net uses to convert the type to a string value and back.  However, since the output value is a string (not an complex object), Json.Net does not output any type information for it.  This causes an issue during deserialization if your property is defined as `object` instead of strongly typed: Json.Net won't be able to find the `TypeConverter`, so it will not be able to convert the string value back into a `Color`.

One way to work around the issue is to wrap the `Color` in another class which has a strongly-typed property for the color value.

```
class ColorHolder
{
    public System.Drawing.Color Value { get; set; }
}
```

Json.Net will then write out type information for the wrapper class, which will allow the nested `Color` struct to be deserialized correctly.  Here is a round-trip demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dict["Rainbow"] = new ColorHolder { Value = Color.FromArgb(10, 20, 30, 40) };

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.WriteLine();

        var d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json, settings);

        ColorHolder holder = (ColorHolder)d["Rainbow"];
        Console.WriteLine("A=" + holder.Value.A);
        Console.WriteLine("R=" + holder.Value.R);
        Console.WriteLine("G=" + holder.Value.G);
        Console.WriteLine("B=" + holder.Value.B);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "Rainbow": {
    "$type": "JsonTest.ColorHolder, JsonTest",
    "Value": "10, 20, 30, 40"
  }
}

A=10
R=20
G=30
B=40
```

Comment: Looks like this would also apply to any type with a `TypeConverter` that can convert to `string`.

Comment: Yes, it definitely would.

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize and deserialize Color as Int32.
For instance, I do that:

```
        private Color _TextColor;
        public Color TextColor
        {
            get => _TextColor;
            set
            {
                if (_TextColor != value)
                {
                    _TextColor = value;
                    PropertyChangedCall("StyleProperty");
                }
            }
        }
        public int TextColorValue
        {
            get => _TextColor.ToArgb();
            set
            {
                if (_TextColor != Color.FromArgb(value))
                {
                    _TextColor = Color.FromArgb(value);
                    PropertyChangedCall("StyleProperty");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

The `System.Drawing.Color` is a structure, and not a class in .NET. That sounds like an answer to your problem. Try to wrap it up with a class, or create your own color class and it should solve it.

Comment: If I modify my original example and change `class B` to `struct B`, `["Bar"]` still gets appropriate `$type` metadata.  So that's not it.

Comment: Why you mention B? You said the problem is with Color type not serialized properly ("Rainbow"). And I say that's because this is a struct and not a class. Read my answer again, please.

Comment: It can't be made any clearer.  Other structs work fine, so the fact that it's a struct is not the cause of the problem.  You do not understand the question.