# Json.Net acting up when adding a second constructor that takes a Color type arguemnt?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have a class that I serialize with Json.Net. I recently have needed to add a `Color` property to the class along with a nice way to set it in the constructor.

```
public class InfoClass
{
    public static Color DefaultColor = Color.SlateBlue;

    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Left { get; set; }
    public int Right { get; set; }
    public Color ColorId { get; set; }

    public InfoClass(String name, int left, int right)
    {
        Name = name;
        Left = left;
        Right = right;
        ColorId = DefaultColor;
    }

    public InfoClass(String name, int left, int right, Color colorId)
    {
        Name = name;
        Left = left;
        Right = right;
        ColorId = colorId;
    }
}
```

I have found that once I add the second constructor I get a exception thrown (I am pretty sure as a result of deserializing this class) at my `Application.Run` in `Program.cs`. It is a `TargetInvocationException` with an inner exception of `NullReferenceException`. The inner exception also notes that the `Data` is `System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal`, which I hold a `List<InfoClass>` within the class I am serializing.

**Seeing as everything works prior to adding this constructor I have to assume that the error lies with it, though I am not sure why?**

Just as a reference upon serialization of a `List<InfoClass>` Json.Net produces the following Json

```
"InfoList": [
{
    "Name": "One",
    "Left": 1,
    "Right": 2,
    "ColorId": "SlateBlue"
},
{
    "Name": "Two",
    "Left": 3,
    "Right": 4,
    "ColorId": "SlateBlue"
}]
```

I have also taken a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584530/json-net-serialization-of-system-drawing-color-with-typenamehandling) which talks about the proper way to serialize a `Color`. I have implemented this technique, along with simply saving the `Color` as its RGB values. All of these methods work to serialize the data, but I am still given the same exception upon deserialization. Though I do not get the error with these methods if the constructor does not exist. So I am thoroughly convinced it is this constructor (but I have been wrong before).

**EDIT:** After a moment of sudden clarity I put a try/catch around the deserialization call and found the exception returned the message

> Unable to find a constructor to use for type [InfoClass]. A class
>   should either have a default constructor, one constructor with
>   arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute.

I guess Json.Net does not like multiple constructors with no default or no marked ones.

Comment: It doesn't add up (in my mind), why would this be causing a `NullReferenceException`?  Are you deserializing something at application start up?

Comment: The application shows the main `Form` but once it is `Shown` I load a user profile that holds a `List` of this class. So it fails once the list is deserialized.

Comment: Maybe you should post the specific code that is throwing.

Comment: I know Json.Net has some specific use cases for "stuff" so I thought this might be one of them. Let me try to create a SSCCE.

Comment: I will post the specific code, but it is just the basic reading of a text file, giving it to Json.Net, and calling deserialize. But again, the exception is thrown all the way up to `Application.Run`, so the specific code is `Application.Run`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a parameterless constructor and annotate it with the `[JsonConstructor]` attribute.

```
public class InfoList
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public InfoList()
    {
    }

    /* your other constructors here */
}
```

Without your json examples I can't truly test but I *have* encountered this problem with multiple constructors before.

**edit:** it looks like you just found the same thing.

Comment: I think the you can keep the multiple constructors as long as you apply the `[JsonConstructor]` attribute to one of them.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to work. Though I wonder, how does Json.Net actually set the values of the properties? Wouldn't I need to make the constructor that sets all public properties?

Comment: @CodingGorilla Yeah, If I mark the second constructor with that tag then "it works". So I have multipel constructors.

Comment: I had an issue where adding `[JsonConstructor]` to one of the existing constructors still failed.  It's possible there was another factor at play, but adding the empty constructor to "brute force" the issue has always worked so far.

Comment: I guess just for my peace of mind I put the tag over the constructor that sets all the properties instead of adding a default; a default doesn't make sense for my class. I have to assume that Json.Net uses Reflection to set the properties then and not a constructor, it only uses the constructor to instantiate the object?